# file size returned from ls - Linux vs OS X

Tags: linux, macos, filesystems

I have been moving a large number of files between a Linux system (`ext3`) and Mac OS X (`HFS`) and have noticed the slight variation in how the file size is reported by the `ls` command.

Having done some digging round the man pages I'm guessing this difference has to do with how the actual data is stored on the disk, and/or how the `ls` command on each system is looking at the size (i.e. disk usage, blocks used, etc.).

However, I'm still confused and wondering if there is a simpler answer to the different file sizes between the two systems.  Is this a difference in the `ls` command, or in the filesystems? etc.

Comment: After expanding any shell aliases, what options are you using? What part of the output of `ls` are you checking? The “total” line from `ls -l` might be different if the filesystems use different block/fragment sizes. If the size in bytes (usually between user/group and date) of a file is different, then you likely have a bad copy. Run `md5`/`sha1`/`openssl md5`/`openssl sha1` on one of the files that shows a difference on each side. If those tools report different hash values then your copy is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's the file system. The command is probably reporting a value as the size on disk rather than the actual size, and since each machine may be using a different cluster size, you see different values. More on the topic [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/66825/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk).

You can use `tune2fs -l` to see how your file system is currently configured.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OSX are you running? Snow Leopard now uses base-10 calculations instead of base-2.  If you're on 10.5 or older, I would attribute it to filesystems. Try comparing filesizes from a FAT32 thumbdrive.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6 still uses base 2 in most of the command line commands including `ls`.