# File size discrepancy in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

While looking at the properties in Explorer there seems to be a discrepancy in the displayed values. One value is presented when I hover the cursor over the file, and the other is displayed in Explorer file attributes field:

[image]

I understand from reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/66825/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk), and its subsequent answers, that there is a difference between "Size” and “Size on disk” that is shown in the File Properties Window.

My question has been refined to this:

Which value is the value shown in Explorer... (Size, or Size on Disk)?

Running Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I believe that the linked duplicate IS a duplicate, even if the title doesn't seem to indicate as much. The reason is maths (which is addressed in the linked duplicate).

Comment: I have refined the question so that is is clearly asking something other than the alleged duplicate.

Comment: Maybe there is no discrepancy at all. Note 5314.2/1024=5.1896… This assumes these `KB` and `MB` you see are really KiB and MiB respectively (and I believe this is exactly the case in Windows). It seems the rounding in two cases is different. I don't know if the values are "size" or "size on disk", but it's possible they are both of the same kind and equal, no discrepancy.